# WebView continues playing flash on back when screen rotated

Tags: android, mobile, webview

I am loading mobile site in a `WebView`. The Flash player does not stop when the back button is pressed. To resolve that, I have added following to my code:

```java
try {
    Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView").getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null).invoke(wv, (Object[]) null);
} catch(Exception e) {
}
```

It has resolved the problem, but when I rotate the screen and press back button, it is still playing flash in back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Honeycomb+ targets, you can add calls to the WebView's onPause() and onResume() in your activity's onPause() and onResume():

// assuming mWebView is assigned in onCreate() ..

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mWebView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mWebView.onResume();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.While pressing back i m not destroying the activity. It moves to the previous page. infact i m doing this in the back press.